# Customize UISearchController in TVOS

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, tvos, uisearchcontroller

i'm working with *UISearchController* in TVOS application. I'm facing few issues in that.

Basically, this controller is embedded in *tabBarController*, and i want:

1- Search bar to be placed **below the tab bar**. Is it possible? I **don't want** to make my tabBar ***translucant*** but to change the frame of search Bar. Is it possible

2- As shown in image, i want the **color** of alphabets and other keys to be pink *(when in focused mode)*. The default color is black (for focus mode) & grey (for normal mode). How to update that?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Hi friend, were you able to solve this, if so, please share? Thanks.

Comment: @AlejandroDavidCotillaRojas, not yet. If you find some solution, please share

Comment: same here. Guys, did you solved the issue?

Comment: @SimónInternacional, No. I shipped the build with default colors